# How to make unique identifier from device?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just want to know what can be used and stored on server from an Apple device (iPod Touch, iPhone or iPad) to make unique identifier? such as IMEI or something... I just need something unique so that my app can do 'once from same device' validation.

thank you.

Comment: The answers to that potential dupe are out of date...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use NSUUID. However this changes, so you can implement it by calling it the first time the app is open and saving it.

```
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
{
        //App has previously launched

}
else
{
    //First launch
    NSString *identifierString = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:identifierString forKey:@"uuidKey"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Edit: for some more information and the options available to you, [check out this great article](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/).

Comment: wow... you're fast and complete with sample code, bro... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on iOS 6.0 or later, you can use `identifierForVendor` from `UIDevice`.

```
NSUUID*   pUUID;
UIDevice* pThisDvc;

pThisDvc = [UIDevice currentDevice];
if ( pThisDvc )
{
    pUUID = [pThisDvc identifierForVendor];
}
```

Comment: Why do we have to check `if (pThisDvc)` ?? Are there any instances when `[UIDevice currentDevice]` does not return a valid object ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider having a look at this [Open source initiative for a universal and persistent UDID solution for iOS](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID#usage)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSUUID* identifier = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];

NSString* uniqueIdentifier = [identifier UUIDString];
```

This returns a unique identifier for the current device, that is unique to each app. Apple recommends using this for general purposes, and `advertisingIdentifier` for purposes of advertising.

> When implementing a system for serving advertisements, use the value
>   in the advertisingIdentifier property of the ASIdentifierManager class
>   instead of this property. Use of that property requires you to follow
>   the guidelines set forth in the class discussion for the proper use of
>   that identifier. For more information, see ASIdentifierManager Class
>   Reference.

...  from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)